# How to create 2nd level property with for JS object using bracketss

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Here's deal. I'm starting with an object literal.

```
var prepObj = {};
```

Then I will be doing a foreach where I'll be adding properties to this object. Basically, in the end it will look something like this (on a larger scale).

```
{
    34 : {
        prop1: myvalue,
        prop2: myvalue,
    }
    87 : {
        prop1: myvalue,
        prop2: myvalue,
    }
    102 : {
        prop1: myvalue,
        prop2: myvalue,
    }
}
```

Throughout the loop I'll be finding a value for a certain property of a certain index (such as prop1 of 87), and creating it for the object.

So, before the loop I'm starting with a blank object.

Then during the loop, I thought I could do:

```
var index_id = 87;
var which_prop = "prop1";
var prop_value = "This is a value.";

prepObj[index_id][which_prop] = prop_value;
```

but when I try this I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop1' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not support [autovivication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification). You must define `prepObj[index_id] = {}` before you define `prepObj[index_id][which_prop] = prop_value`.

This is because `prepObj[index_id]` is initially not defined. Thus, you are trying to set the `prop1` property on `prepObj[index_id]` which is `undefined`. You avoid this by making `prepObj[index_id]` some defined value.

If you're worried about clobbering `prepObj[index_id]` with a new object each time, you can test that the value is already set by either:

- `index_id in prepObj` - this tests that prepObj already has an entry whose key is the value of `index_id`
- `typeof prepObj[index_id] != "undefined"` - this tests if the value of `prepObj[index_id]` is not `undefined`
- `prepObj[index_id] || {}` - this evaluates to `prepObj[index_id]` if it's not a falsy value (like `undefined`); otherwise it evaluates to a new object

Comment: Ooh! An answer AND a new piece of vocabulary. I like this. How can I first test whether or not prepObj[index_id] has been instantiated (to avoid it being overwritten)? (Asked before answer was edited to include suggested answer).

Comment: @Pete `prepObj[index_id] = prepObj[index_id] || {};`

Comment: Is there any advantage to testing for BOTH index_id in prepObj and typeof prepObj[index_id] != "undefined"?

Comment: @Pete Maybe? A *failed* `in` test necessarily implies that the value is `undefined`. However, a *passed* `in` test might mean a key whose value is `undefined` or any other value -- it just means that the key exists. If you're not explicitly assigning properties to `undefined`, all of those test will probably work for your simple case.

Comment: So, would the most elegant way to write it be: prepObj[index_id] = (index_id in prepObj) ? prepObj[index_id] : {};

Comment: Probably the most JS-idomatic way is exactly what jbabey wrote using an OR operator: `prepObj[index_id] = prepObj[index_id] || {};` This works great as long as you are sure that `prepObj[index_id]` will never deliberately be a falsy value like `false`, `0`, or `""`. If you know it will only ever be an object or `undefined`, this is exactly what you want. Otherwise, your proposed code works well, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
prepObj[index_id] = {};
prepObj[index_id][which_prop] = prop_value;
```

Comment: Please explain the problem and your solution, don't just write "try this".