# Deep setting of object key-values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
var obj = {};
obj.bar = 'w00p!';           //works
obj.foo.bar = 'there it is'; //throws error because bar is not set
```

Could you ever make `obj.foo.bar =` work if `obj.foo` is not set?

Is there an elegant way to set a deep variable in an object in JavaScript? In the same spirit as mkdir's -p option: `mkdir -p a/deep/dir`

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to create 2nd level property with for JS object using bracketss](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20380504/710446)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked questions, since it is addressing the general case of "autovivification for JavaScript", whereas the linked questions are seeking specific solutions for unique cases.